# Class Loading Code i.e. working with Eclipse not Working in LISA

Tags: java, web-services, testing, classloader

My issue is the follwing code

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class myClass = myClassLoader.loadClass("com.Calculator.add"); 
//com.Calculator is the package name.. add is the class name
Object ClassInstance = myClass.newInstance();
Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod(functionName,new Class[] { String.class }); 
//functionName has the method name of class
output = (String) myMethod.invoke(ClassInstance,new Object[] { "String Argument" }); 
//as add method has a argument of string
```

In Lisa MatchScript this code works till the line

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
```

But when i checked the same in Eclipse the whole code block above is working perfectly Fine..

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: For what testing part do you use LISA (e.g part of a jUnit)? And what LISA do you use, Google have many references to different LISA.

Comment: I am using LISA 6.0.10 ITKO and using it for Webservices testing. Hosted on a Virtualised Service Environment currently.

Comment: And the above code is written in MatchScript of the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer..
The Jar files were to be placed in lib insted of HotDeploy.
The classLoader couldnt locate the JAR files from the HotDeploy